# Какие средства программирования лучше использовать для построения чертежа по заданным параметрам?

Tags: графика

Например: нужно сделать такую программу : на вход поступает некоторое количество параметров того, что нужно нарисовать и выводится изображение фигуры по этим параметрам.
К примеру нарисовать нужно вот это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не хочется делать что-нибудь вроде:

```
DrawLine...
DrawLine...
.
..
DrawLine..
```

Нужен инструмент получше, подскажите какую-нибудь библиотеку для какого-нибудь языка программирования, или еще чего-нибудь.

Comment: Ну так вынесите описание линий в массив и вызывайте `DrawLine()` во время перебора его элементов.